# Feature Rotation Exception

Tags: arcobjects, c#, error, fields-attributes, schematics

I am getting an error when I try to change the value of a feature's Rotation Value.
I have a schematic feature that I would like to rotate by changing the field's ROTATION value, but everytime I try to set the new value I get this error.
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Here is the part of the code where I set the value

```c#
ISchematicRelationController controller = new SchematicRelationControllerClass();
var parentContainer = controller.FindParent(duct);
if (parentContainer == null) {
   var rotIdx = parentContainer.Fields.FindField("ROTATION");
   var idx = duct.SchematicElement.Fields.FindField("ROTATION");
   if (rotIdx > -1) {
      Duct.SchematicElement.Value[rotIdx] = 45;
      parentContainer.Value[rotIdx] = 65; ------> this is where the exception occurs
                    }
```

Comment: aybody ? any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this field took double values so the answer was to set it as follows:

```
Duct.SchematicElement.Value[rotIdx] = 45;
  parentContainer.Value[rotIdx] = 65d; or 65.0
```

Comment: +1, Glad you found a solution to your problem even though it took almost 5 months :)

Comment: yeah it was a simple problem that I solved back then, but I was going through my account so I can post answers on the stuff that I have solved but never answered on here haha.

Comment: It is much appreciated that you're coming back to post your solutions, I'm sure this will help others in similar situations in the future =)